# How to use node module that browser doesn't support in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, browserify

I want to use webtorrent module in browser. Browser doesn't support that module natively. So I tried to use browserify to fix this problem, but I am just running on bunch of errors.
I used tsify to transform .ts files into .js files, then esmify to support ecsm modules and then browserify to make a bundle.js.

This is a command:

```
browserify src/main.ts -p [ tsify --esModuleInterop --moduleResolution node] -p [ esmify --global-name App ] --node > bundle.js
```

And I get this error:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

Can anyone suggest the other way around for this or help me with this, is the command even right?

Comment: This module requires network and udp access, you won't be able to use it anyway

Comment: Feross Aboukhadijeh, the creator of the module in his talks showed how to use it in the browser. And I managed to write a .js file in which I included that module and seeded something. But I just can't do that with the framework.
PeerTube app which is open source also implements it in the client. I will try to see how they do it.